# Air circulating upwards due to cold floors

Tags: insulation, heating

I did an experiment in a bedroom of mine with a lot of incense, I got the room to the point where there was a thick cloud of smoke. What I noticed is that there was a constant upwards flow of smoke. I have baseboard heat but the heaters were turned off during the experiment. I’m wondering if my floors are so cold (since I don’t have insulation in the basement ceiling) that it’s causing the floor level air to be so cold that the heat starts to rise to the top of the room so quickly that it takes a lot of heat power in order to break the circulation of air and actually feel the hot air. I am wondering if this is a possibility? I insulated all of the walls and ceiling with r19 batt insulation. I’m wondering also if that isn’t a high enough R value. I like in the middle of Illinois so it gets cold here.

After this I also noticed that all of my fans spin clockwise , they’re all picking up the air and throwing it toward the ceiling, I don’t think this is the problem since they’re not always running but if I switch the fans to go counterclockwise would it work more in my favor since it would be taking the *hot air* close to the ceiling and throwing it back down to the floor?

Comment: Basic physical phenomena heat rises at the same time cold air sinks because it is heavier than warm air. This indicates to me the floor is warmer or something on it is.

Comment: fan direction doesn't really matter for most room sizes, it all mixes up the same so that the floor and ceiling are closer in temp than without a fan, no matter the direction. It's nice to have a breeze hitting you if you don't have AC, so "summer mode" usually fires down, but the net thermal effect is basically a wash.

Comment: Having the fans blow air upward helps with winter heating because it does help circulate the warmer air downward with _less breeze feeling_ that makes you feel cooler. In the summer, you switch the fans to blow directly downward (even though it's moving warmer air down), because the breeze makes you _feel_ cooler (wind chill, technically).

Answer (score 2):

Basic physical phenomena heat rises at the same time cold air sinks because cold air is heavier than warm air. This indicates to me the fan, or the floor is warmer or something on it is. I spin my fans so they push heat from the ceiling down in the winter an up in the summer.